# Connecting Heroku mLab via terminal

Tags: heroku, terminal, mlab

I am able to connect to Heroku mLab database via terminal with one and only user with admin rights, but from the terminal I am not able to perform any operation on my collection.

getting this error:

db.shoppinglist.find({})

Error: error: {
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1589249488, 3),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on shoppinglist to execute command { find: \"shoppinglist\", filter: {}, lsid: { id: UUID(\"c9ed079b-294c-4e1d-b147-45894c2dd936\") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1589249472, 3), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 2710EE60D1197B2CD32D1EE8B0A2FA5446E4AF3D), keyId: 6779753615021047809 } }, $db: \"shoppinglist\" }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1589249488, 3),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"c69ASzyiNK+zVrP1x2xxBlInzDc="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6779753615021047809")
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake I was making

I was doing
use colletionName

Instead of 
use databaseName

Fixed the problem.